# How to replace more than a string in one line?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I want to insert "OB" before every vowel. I have tried the code below:

```
String out=txt.toUpperCase();

out=out.replaceAll("A","OBA");
out=out.replaceAll("E","OBE");
out=out.replaceAll("I","OBI");
out=out.replaceAll("O","OBO");
out=out.replaceAll("U","OBU");
out=out.replaceAll("Y","OBY");
```

When I use that code above, it replaces `A` with `OBA`, but then when it comes to replacing `O` to `OBO` it replaces the `O` from the original text and also the `O` in `OBA`.
For example, for `"I WON'T"` I want the output `"OBI WOBON'T"`, but instead it gives `"OBOBI WOBON'T"` as the `O` from `OBI` from the first line has been treated as a vowel.

I need a solution which doesn't replace the new `O` from the encryption.

Comment: Iterate on the string, and replace manually each char (if you don't want to mess with regexes).

Comment: This is not encryption, it is an encoding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `replaceAll` takes regex, you can use references to captured elements in your replacement string:

```
out=out.replaceAll("[AEIOUY]", "OB$0");
```

- `[AEIOUY]` captures a single character from the `AEIOUY` list
- `$0` in the replacement string stands for the character that has been captured.

Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/LKOA8B).

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to the matched group with the `$1`, so replacing with `AB$1`:

```
out.replaceAll("([AEIOUY])", "OB$1")
```

Comment: @deepakl No, it does not: `"I WON'T".replaceAll("([AEIOUY])", "OB$1")` in Scala REPL `res0: String = OBI WOBON'T`, which is the expected.

Comment: Sorry, if I missed something, I was trying it in java and got IndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: Well, they should behave the same way and should not throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Yes, they are very similar (and we created almost simultaneously). The main difference is genericity. With my approach more complex conditions can be applied by changing the regex, while with the other it requires more attention on change. (Which Java version do you observe IOOBE?)

Comment: I am using 1.8.0_131

Comment: It works well for me: `class X {
    public static void main(String[] sss) {
        String ss = "I WON'T".replaceAll("([IO])", "OB$1");
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
}`, output: `OBI WOBON'T`, Java version 1.8.0_121.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use regexes:

```
HashMap<Character, String> replace = new HashMap<Character, String>() {{
            put('A',"OBA");
            put('E',"OBE");
            put('I',"OBI");
            put('O',"OBO");
            put('U',"OBU");
            put('Y',"OBY");
}};

final StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
String test = "I WON'T";

test
 .chars()
 .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
 .forEach(c -> res.append(replace.getOrDefault(c, Character.toString(c))));
System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

move "O","OBO" to the start will prevent duplication

```
String out=txt.toUpperCase();

out=out.replaceAll("O","OBO");
out=out.replaceAll("A","OBA");
out=out.replaceAll("E","OBE");
out=out.replaceAll("I","OBI");
out=out.replaceAll("U","OBU");
out=out.replaceAll("Y","OBY");
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this can also be done, replace OB with '-@' (any 2 characters that we can be sure of would not appear in the string) and in the end replace them with OB:

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "I WON'T";

```
text = text.replaceAll("A", "-@A");
text = text.replaceAll("E", "-@E");
text = text.replaceAll("I", "-@I");
text = text.replaceAll("O", "-@O");
text = text.replaceAll("U", "-@U");
text = text.replaceAll("Y", "-@Y");
System.out.println(text);       
text = text.replaceAll("-@", "OB");     
System.out.println(text);
}
```

output

-@I W-@ON'T
OBI WOBON'T

Comment: Generally it's bad design to use intermediate variable value, and require additional replaceAll call. FYI, I haven't down vote :)